# Can not assign data in subscribe

Tags: angular, parsing, post, null, request

I have some problem with post method. I always get empty segmentdata object in my temporarySegment. I do the same way with number and it is work. variable result in subscribe is SegmentData, and in console.log i receive an expected response. How is it possible?
My method:

```
  onGetSegmentsClick(size: number) {
    debugger;
    if (size > 0) {
        let counter = 0;
        let temporarySegment = new SegmentData();
        while (counter < size) {
            this.segmentService.getSegment(counter + 1, this.elementId, this.documentId).subscribe(result => {
                console.log("get segment request is sended");
                temporarySegment = result;
                console.log("gotten message is:", result);
            });
            ModalComponent.segmentsCollection.push(new SegmentData());
            ModalComponent.segmentsCollection[ModalComponent.segmentsCollection.length - 1] =
                ModalComponent.newer.TemporaryObjectEqualizer(temporarySegment);
            ModalComponent.segmentsCollection[ModalComponent.segmentsCollection.length - 1].SegmentDataId =
                counter + 1;
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

My getSegment method:

```
  getSegment(segmentId: number, elementId: string, documentId: string) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-type", "application/json");
    let input = {
        "elementId": elementId,
        "documentId": documentId,
        "segmentNumber": segmentId
    }
    let sendingData = JSON.stringify(input);
    let urlPost = "https://localhost:44375/api/data/SendSegmentData";
    let output = new AsyncSubject<SegmentData>();
    let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers,
        method: RequestMethod.Post,
        url: urlPost
    });
    this.http.post(urlPost, sendingData, options)
        .subscribe(result => {
            output.next(result.json());
            output.complete();
        });
    return output;
}
```

Class SegmentData on client is equal to the relevant class on server. My response is parsed perfectly. How to fix this?
Thank you in advance))

Comment: You need to understand asynchronism. When you subscribe(), you send a request. Then the rest of the code in the while loop is executed immediately after. Much, much later, asynchronously, when the requests has been processed by a server thousands of kilometers away, and the server has sent back a response, the callback function that you passed to subscribe is executed. So you can't possibly access the value from the response immediately after you sent the request. You can't eat your toast immediately after you've put it in the toaster. You need to eat it after the toaster told you it's ready.

Comment: Thanks, but how to wait until response is back?

Comment: You don't wait. You put the code that needs access to the response inside the callback passed to subscribe().

Answer (score 0):

Code next to subscribe call will execute without waiting for subscribe call to end so while loop will run without waiting for the subscribe to complete and run. Below code is changed to place all the code within subscribe call.

```
onGetSegmentsClick(size: number) {
    debugger;
    if (size > 0) {
        let counter = 0;
        let temporarySegment = new SegmentData();
        while (counter < size) {
            this.segmentService.getSegment(counter + 1, this.elementId, this.documentId).subscribe(result => {
                console.log("get segment request is sended");
                temporarySegment = result;
                console.log("gotten message is:", result);

            ModalComponent.segmentsCollection.push(new SegmentData());
            ModalComponent.segmentsCollection[ModalComponent.segmentsCollection.length - 1] =
                ModalComponent.newer.TemporaryObjectEqualizer(temporarySegment);
            ModalComponent.segmentsCollection[ModalComponent.segmentsCollection.length - 1].SegmentDataId =
                counter + 1;
            counter++;
          });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already explained what is happening. the code that follows your `subscribe()` inside your while loop actually runs *before* the subscribe function, since that function only runs asynchronously after the response returns from the server. So at the time you try to use the value of `temporarySegment`, it is still empty.

You asked:

> how to wait until response is back?

You could use the async/await coding pattern to make your async code run in line with the rest of your procedure.  First add the `async` a modifier to your function declaration:

```
async onGetSegmentsClick(size:number){ ...
```

Then turn the observable chain into a promise and use the `await` modifier to tell the JS engine to wait for the result before proceeding:

```
temporarySegment = await this.segmentService.getSegment(...).toPromise();
// here you can use temporarySegment immediately
```

[See the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Comment: Thank you fro answer. Latter I found sending request in cycle bad idea, so just get all array as response at one request.